# Integral on a quarter circle using Cartesian coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$ \iint_D \frac{xy}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} dx dy $$, where

$$ D=\{(x,y):x≥0,y≥0,x^2+y^2≤1\}. $$

I want to solve it using Cartesian coordinates.

I use the fact that

$$ \iint_D \frac{xy}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} dxdy = \int_0^1\!\int_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}\frac{xy}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} dxdy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{y}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} - \frac{y^3}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}}\right) dy $$

But after that I get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle I = \int_0^1\!\int_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}\frac{xy}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} dx \ dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y(1-y^2)}{({1+y^{2})}^{2}} dy$

Substituting $\displaystyle 1+y^2 = t$,

$ \displaystyle y \ dy = \frac{1}{2}dt, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \implies 1 \leq t \leq 2$

So integral becomes,

$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{2-t}{t^2} dt$

and it is straightforward from here.